# How to import images using webpacker in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, datatables, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to use [jquery.datatables](https://datatables.net/manual/installation) using webpacker in rails 6.  I have

```
#app/javascript/packs/application.js
...
require("datatables.net")
require("datatables.net-dt")
...
```

Then I have

```
#app/javascript/packs/
@import '../stylesheets/datatables.scss';
```

and then

```
#app/javascript/stylesheets/datatables.scss
@import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables';
```

but the webpacker-dev-server gives following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/sort_asc.png' in '/Users/app/javascript/packs'
resolve '../images/sort_asc.png' in '/Users/app/javascript/packs'
  using description file: /Users/app/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/app/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/images/sort_asc.png)
      no extension
```

The directory structure for `datatables.net-dt` is as follows

```
datatables.net-dt
  css
  images
  js
```

and there are five png images in images folder. Presumably they are background images for the css.  How do I load these images, ideally without having to name each one?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, though I do plan to have a go at it in the next few weeks.